# HTTP Post Only works with default HttpClient, not with OkHttpClient

Tags: android, httpclient, okhttp

I'm working on a project which requires me to send a post request to
http://sagecell.sagemath.org/kernel (just a post, no data)along with two extra headers,
Accept-Encoding:identity and accepted_tos:true.

This works fine if using the default httpClient like so:

```
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();

String url = UrlUtils.getKernelURL();

httpPost.setURI(URI.create(url));

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(HEADER_ACCEPT_ENCODING,VALUE_IDENTITY));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(HEADER_TOS,"true"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

webSocketResponse = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), WebSocketResponse.class);
inputStream.close();
```

However if I want to use the same thing using the OkHttpClient, it gives me a 403 error:

```
httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

public static final MediaType jsonMediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonMediaType, "");

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .addHeader(HEADER_ACCEPT_ENCODING, VALUE_IDENTITY)
        .addHeader(HEADER_TOS, "true")
        .url(url)
        .post(body) //I've tried null here as well
        .build();

Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

Log.i(TAG,"STATUS CODE"+response.code()); //This is 403
```

This is the same story with libraries like Ion and even HttpUrlConnection, only the Apache Client seems to work.

Any answers as to why this isn't working would be appreciated.

Comment: do you post your whole logcat

Comment: It doesn't crash, the status code is just 403 when it should be 2xx.

Comment: http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/48782017564/trying-out-squares-okhttp-client

Answer (score 0):

error 403 means its forbidden by the server.
And in the first case(while using default httpclient ) you are not adding header, you are just adding a name-value pair to the entity.
to add a header you should use

```
httpPost.addHeader("key","value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request body is empty. You should provide a form-encoded request body, or a JSON request body, and the corresponding content type.

If you want, [MimeCraft](https://github.com/square/mimecraft) will build you a form-encoded request body, and [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) will do JSON.

Comment: But that's the thing, it's a post with an empty request body.

Comment: An empty string isn't valid JSON.